# UITableView has only one field

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I tried to load an array and show items of array on tableview.
My tableview show only one fields of web service.

e.g  if branchname is ABC.Tableview show me 40 ABC row
Tableview has 40 same items.I want to load all 40 items

My codes:

my array

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Parse XML codes

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:    (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Branchnames"] ) {
        if (!retornoSOAP) {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    teveRetorno = YES;
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if (teveRetorno) {
        [myArray addObject:string];
        NSLog(@"My Array %@",myArray);
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Branchnames"] ) {
        NSLog(@"My Array %@",myArray);
       [[self tableView]reloadData];
       retornoSOAP = nil;
       teveRetorno = NO;
    }
}
```

Table Codes:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

   return 40;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
 cell.textLabel.text =[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show result of NSLog(@"My Array %@",myArray); after parsing?

Comment: Can you show output of NSLog of myArray?

Comment: Did you checked the output  of ` NSLog(@"My Array %@",myArray);` ? I think the array also have 40 ABC.

Comment: Yes I see all result @HinataHyuga

Comment: Also the implementation of `foundCharacters:` have issues. Never expect it'll read full content at a time, it can call this method many times for a particular element.

Comment: add that output in your code.

Comment: Are you sure that , the parser returning 40 items ?

Comment: why you are given 40 sections? is it necessary?

Comment: @MidhunMP there are no 40 same items.I see other results in log

Comment: @manujmv I did 100 sections.It is same.show only one field

Comment: Put NSLog array.count in number of numberOfRows method

Comment: @MehmetAkyel: What is the need of those 40 sections ? Just return 1 from that method and check, howmany elements are there. If there is only one row, then your array have only one element, else your above comment will not be true (there are no 40 same items.I see other results in log)

Comment: Are you parsing in right way? and getting data in array what you want to display in table?

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh I want to display all branch names on table.It show only one branch name

Comment: @MidhunMP I dont need 40 sections.How can I display number of total branch names by log ?

Comment: I think , the tableView not getting reload . It s showing one row when the ViewController gets loaded .thats it

Comment: Just remove numberOfSectionsInTableView: and then try again.

Comment: @MehmetAkyel: Did you checked my above comment ? Did you try that ? Just return 1 from `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

Comment: my log is here http://pastie.org/8036837

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh  I tried your answer but it is same.Show me only one field on table.No all fields

Comment: @MidhunMP just only has one field when return 1

Comment: @MehmetAkyel: Then the answer is simple. Your array have only one element. Then you'll ask how did you get those logs. It is from `foundCharacters:` method . Change the `didEndElement:` NSLog like: `NSLog(@"Full Array %@",myArray);`. Surely it'll print one element. You used same NSLog for those two methods, that's why the confusion happened

Comment: @MidhunMP you say my array have only one element but I see all elementS on log.I will change which part ?

Comment: @MehmetAkyel: did you checked my above comment ? You are using the NSLog on foundCharacters method also. comment it then check the log from didEndElement

Comment: @MidhunMP I checked.I removed NSLog from foundCharacters.There is NSLog only in didEndElement and I see all results.But there is one field on table.my tableview is here http://postimg.org/image/3pfdh8xi9/  and my results in didEnd is here http://pastebin.com/ARfFJjvC

Comment: Out of curiosity is it only providing the last value that was committed into the Array?

Comment: @D80Buckeye It show me only last value.Why ? I did not found my mistake in my codes

Comment: @MehmetAkyel: Check my answer. Issue with allocating the array each time. The array have only one element. I found the issue from your log. If you provided it with your question, it'll be easy and won't take this much of comment and time :)

Comment: remove this line retornoSOAP = nil;

Comment: I removed this line but it is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with this line:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You are allocating the array each time when a `Branchnames` tag comes. So the array will lose the previous content. And will have only the last object inserted.

Implement methods like:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:    (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Branchnames"] )
   {
     teveRetorno = YES;
   }
   else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"yourTopLevelXMLTag"]) //yourTopLevelXMLTag = ArizalarGetirResult
   {
     myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
  if (teveRetorno)
  {

    [myArray addObject:string];

  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Branchnames"] )
  {
    teveRetorno = NO;
  }
  else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"yourTopLevelXMLTag"]) //yourTopLevelXMLTag = ArizalarGetirResult
  {
    [[self tableView]reloadData];
  }
}
```

Comment: @MehmetAkyel: is the `parserDidStartDocument` is calling ?

Comment: Can you post your xml structure ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31651/discussion-between-mehmet-akyel-and-midhun-mp)

Answer (score 1):

For my data model I typically create a singleton that is exposed to both the XMLParser as well as my ViewController so that when I'm parsing my XML...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rootElement"])
    {
        currElement = [[mySingleton alloc] init];
        currentElement.currentElementAttribute = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"type"];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"somethingElse"])
    {
       //don't need to init another currElement here
    }
  }
```

and I can do whatever I want with the data in my ViewController...

```
self.myLabel.text = currElement.currentElementAttribute;
```

Of course this should also work when using an NSMutableDictionary or NSArray.Typically I'll create my singletons like this...

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)mySingletonDictionary
{
    static NSMutableDictionary *singletonInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singletonInstance = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    });
    return singletonInstance;
}
```

That's an Arc-safe way to instantiate a singleton that can only be instantiated once.